# I need a rewrite rule for opencart htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, opencart, http-status-code-301

Can someone can give me an htaccess rewrite that wont break when I enable seo url's in opencart. I had a 301 htaccess rule that redirected all old urls from our oscommerce website but when I enable seo urls within the new opencart admin panel the redirect for the old urls no longer works. I'm thinking that it may have something to do with the fact that oscommerce and opencart both have directories named /catalog at the root directory level. Please help!!! Below, I have pasted the rewrite rule that I was using to redirect all of the old urls to the site's homepage...

```
RewriteRule ^catalog/product_info\.php$ / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Move this rule as the first rule in your .htaccess.

Comment: After `RewriteEngine On`. In general, be careful of the order of rewrites, so that if you rewrite something that will require further rewrites, it is done before those other rewrites.